# NullReferenceException when instantiating

Tags: visual-studio-2008, visual-c++

I'm getting that exception on this line

```
this->root = new node;
```

In Visual C++. Note that `node` is a `struct` and `root` is a pointer to the node struct (null before this line)

How can I solve this, or why is this caused?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Solved
class instantiation was deleted by the Visual studio form designer, but the method still get called, an the method is not static, anyone know why?